# Web API: Sending a notification using Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: web-applications, google-cloud-messaging, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to send a notification to my android clients using Google Cloud Messaging however I get this error:

> The name 'Services' does not exist in the current context

My Code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/loginuser")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> LoginUser(string email, string password)
{
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "message", "Welcome"}
            };

            GooglePushMessage message = new GooglePushMessage(data, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
            try
            {
                //This is where I get the error
                var result = await Services.Push.SendAsync(message);
                Services.Log.Info(result.State.ToString());
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Services.Log.Error(ex.Message, null, "Push.SendAsync Error");
            }

            return Ok("Healthy"});
}
```

I have properly referenced everything that is needed. Still I get this error?

Comment: Are you using a plain Web API or Azure Mobile Services?  The 'Services' type is only available on Mobile Services.